# Can’t install scikit-learn for python on Mac - wrong directory

Tags: macos, python

I’m tearing my hair out! (Not much left!) When I run easy_install -U scikit-learn as admin I get the following error:

Admin$ easy_install -U scikit-learn

**error: can't create or remove files in install directory
The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:
    [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-42472.pth'
The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:
    /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/
Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative
access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
variable.**

here is my system info:

Running Yosemite 10.10.5
Python 2.7
“which python” yields /usr/bin/python 
“which easy_install” yields /usr/bin/easy_install

I’ve tried everything and haven’t seen any good answers to this on various forums. If anyone can help, I’d really appreciate it!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check and see who owns the `site-packages` directory by using

```
ls -l /Library/Python/2.7/
```

You'll get results similar to this:

```
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel  102 Jan 13 17:58 site-packages
```

The third column (that shows `root` above), shows the directory owner. In the above example, this directory is owned by root. I've seen similar errors related to this. I know that you stated you are running these commands as Admin, but prepending these install commands with sudo has worked for me, however, it will install the package globally:

```
sudo easy_install -U scikit-learn
```

Comment: Wow! That was too simple! Using sudo command above as you suggested fixed the install problem. I did get about 36 warnings, but so far its working.  Thanks Chaz!